# Formatting Json for WebAPI 2 from Ember-Data

Tags: json, generics, asp.net-web-api, ember-data

I've been struggling with this problem for a few days now and was hoping someone could help me out. I've got an ember front end which communicates with an API written in C#.

I'm making a an update (PUT) request but the model comes through with all the properties as null. The reason for this is because the API expects

```
{ 
  "Type":1,
  "Name":"Hello World"
}
```

but ember sends it in the format of

```
{
  "Object":
  { 
   "Type":1,
   "Name":"Hello World"
  }
}
```

I've seen solutions where you can add a custom JsonConverter onto the API Model, but this has to have it's own converter for each model. I'd like to know if someone help me with a generic one that I can apply to any model.

Here's an example of one that is specific for the profile model, I can't seem to get it to work as a generic though.

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ProfileConverter))]
    public class Profile
    {
        public string LoginId { get; set; }
        public bool NewProfileOptIn { get; set; }
    }
```

and the converter

```
public class ProfileConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Log.Information("Reading Json from ProfileSetting");
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token["ProfileSetting"] != null)
        {
            JObject inner = token["ProfileSetting"].Value<JObject>();
            if (CheckJsonProperty(inner, "login_id") && CheckJsonProperty(inner, "new_profile_opt_in"))
            {
                Profile model = new Profile
                {
                    LoginId = inner["login_id"].ToString(),
                    NewProfileOptIn = (bool)inner["new_profile_opt_in"]
                };
                return model;
            }
            return null;
        }
        Log.Error("Invalid Model Name Passed - Expected 'ProfileSetting'");
        return null;
    }

    private bool CheckJsonProperty(JObject objectToCheck, string expectedJsonProperty)
    {
        if (objectToCheck[expectedJsonProperty] != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        Log.Error("Invalid or Missing Model Property Name Passed - Expected '" + expectedJsonProperty + "'");
        return false;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If any one has any reading resources or examples that would help, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

**VB.Net**

This Example has been coded with Json.Net.

So I'm working with Vb.net but this should work in C# the same way.
I've been able to do it without an JsonConverter as follows:

```
Public Class TestController
    Inherits ApiController

    <HttpGet> 
    Public Function Index() As String

        Dim o As New JObject
        o.Add("Data", 10)
        Dim j As New JObject
        j.Add("Object", o)

        Dim obj = j.ToObject(Of EmberDataObject(Of TestObject))()

        Return "200 - OK"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class EmberDataObject(Of T)
    <JsonProperty("Object")>
    Public Property DataObject As T
End Class

Public Class TestObject
    Public Property Data As Integer
End Class
```

In the above example the JsonObject with this mark up

```
{
  "Object": {
    "Data": 10
  }
}
```

can be transformed easily. You can then access the nested Type as `obj.DataObject`. Through the set JsonProperty Attribute you can omit the Object key word which at least in Vb is not a legal Property name.

**C#**

The C# translation would be like this:

```
public class EmberDataObject<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("Object")
    public T DataObject {get; set;}
}

public class TestData
{
    public int Data {get; set;}
}
```

And then referencing this from your Controller as follows:

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    public IActionResult Post(EmberDataObject<TestData> emberObject)
    {
        /// Inner Object Available as emberObject.Object
    }
}
```